# view angle independant focal point

Tags: optics, lenses

Is there any way to design a lens or system of lenses where I see the same part of the image below the lens, irrespective of direction from where I am viewing. In the image uploaded, there is a black dot near the focal length of the lens. This black dot will be visible magnified to me if I look at it from above. but if I look at it from sideways, the focal point will shift. So, is there any lens or lens system that can be designed where I can see the same magnified black dot, whether I am viewing the dot in direction perpendicular to it or at 90 degrees in either direction? A lens or lens system where focal point is not dependent on the direction of view? The light rays can be assumed to be collimated as viewing will be from a distance.

[image: series of lenses]

Comment: A lens is (to first order) an optical Fourier transformer that goes from angle relative to the optical axis to displacement on the focal plane, so the answer is negative. What you are trying to do also violates the second law of thermodynamics since your design, as shown, could actually change the Etendue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply....I don't know much about Etendue, but if what you say is correct, how does fish eye or wide eye lens focus light from 180 degrees to a single point..? does this not mean that if I view an object kept at say focal length or near focal length, then I should be able to see the magnified version of that object from any angle that I View. we did

Comment: now magnification is given by M=F/(F-d), F being focal length and d being distance of the object- X in our case. Say we adjust the magnification to 10, so we will be able to see 10 times bigger X from the lens. Now since fish-eye lens brings all light to the focal length  from entire 180 degrees , will it not mean that I will see magnified X from all the 180 degrees and will not see W and Y at all?

Comment: All I am interested is in having an arrangement where I can only see magnified X from all directions and not see W and Y...that is,  I want to see say only 33% or say even 50% of the focal plane only from all directions, I want the remaining 66 or 50 % to stay hidden...irrespective of the angle from where I am viewing.

Comment: Going by the example, I have arc length L of say 10mm so I will define my focal plane a circle having area of pi*D^2/4= 314/4=7.85 sq mm approx. Now I want my lens to focus only on say "the same" 2 to 3 sq mm area in the middle only and make the other peripheral area hidden when viewed from lens from any direction....may be I have framed by question wrong, but I am trying to achieve the above and want to know  if its possible...

Comment: correction :  I have wrongly mentioned the plane as Focal plane in diagram, its actually object plane where I will be keeping the object. The distance of object plane from Focal plane will determine image magnification..

Comment: We can say I am looking at system which is opposite of Lenticular Lens. In lenticular lens I see different images from different angles. Here I want same "magnified" image from all the 180 degree angle of view.

Comment: Lenses do not focus light from different direction on one point. They focus light from one point in the plane of the object onto one point in their image plane. Different points on objects are being focused on different points in the image plane. That is the function of a lens.

Comment: I am attaching a ray-trace of fish eye lens- taken from a patent I found while searching online. The collimated rays from different directions seem to focus on the surface R5 of Lens E3. This surface R5 is much smaller than the lower surface of Lens E1.

Assuming there is no Lens E3 and surface R5 is my Object plane, then can we say that the fish eye will only show image of object (X in our case) on surface R5 and other objects ( W and Y) which are below the lens E1  but not on R5 will not be visible? I am doing some modifications on the diagram and uploading it.

Comment: And can this X be magnified based on its position w.r.t the focal length of the fish-eye lens?

Comment: Patents are legal documents, they are not required to be technically or scientifically correct and very often they are neither, either because the inventor or his patent attorney do not know better, because they do not care or, and I have seen this multiple times, patents can be written to actually deceive about the actual function of the invention, so they are false on purpose! NEVER use a patent anywhere else but in court.

Comment: Ok. but the ray trace diagram of a fish eye lens will be same...please have a look at it and let me know if the ray trace is wrong.

Comment: Looks accurate enough... and it shows exactly what I said it would... different directions of incoming beams will be focused on different points in the image plane.

Comment: Thanks. I believe we can design the object plane to be small enough such that only magnified version of "X" is visible from all directions...

Comment: What you believe is of no concern to nature, I am afraid. Please read up on Etendue and try to understand what that means for imaging lenses.

Comment: This is a nice article on Etendue. Uploading it in case any one else wants to read the same.


@CuriousOne, I believe what this means is that I cant Magnify and Increase the angle of View at the same time, to increase the angle of view, I have to necessarily have to de-magnify or minify the image...please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: this is the link....


http://www.mikewoodconsulting.com/articles/Protocol%20Winter%202012%20-%20Etendue.pdf

Comment: but there is one more thing:  Etendue can remain constant or it can increase as light propagates through an optic, but it cannot decrease as per laws of nature,...so it is possible to increase the Etendue...so is it possible to increase both source size and angle??

Comment: quoting directly from Wikipedia--" Conservation of etendue:

As shown below, etendue is conserved as light travels through free space and at refractions or reflections. It is then also conserved as light travels through optical systems where it undergoes perfect reflections or refractions. However, if light was to hit, say, a diffuser, its solid angle would increase, increasing the etendue. Etendue can then remain constant or it can increase as light propagates through an optic, but it cannot decrease. "

so is the solution just adding diffuser to the lens as suggested by Madan Ivan..??

Comment: this will be at cost of brightness of the system I guess..

Comment: You were talking about an imaging system. Of course you can spread the light with a diffusor all over the place... that's not am imaging system, though.

Comment: I am talking about a passive source....the W,X, Y are not light sources they are written on piece of paper. They don't emit light on their own, they only reflect ambient light which I want to See from different angles...I am not sure whether you call in an imaging system or not, but that's what I am talking about...

Also is it possible to arrange many small lenses in circular arc so that all their focal point is on X.., then I can view the X but not W and Y from all directions... I will try to attach a diagram shortly..

Comment: None of that matters. The lenses you were talking about are all imaging systems. Of course you can illuminate $4\pi$ from a single point, you won't need any lenses for that.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Did some reading...what I believe is that if I want to increase the magnification ( apparent increase in area ) then it will be at cost of reduction of angle as etendue= area*angle will remain constant.  to increase the angle of view, i have to necessarily decrease the apparent area i.e there will always be de-magnification.  Magnification and increase in angle cant happen both at same time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So in my case, the angle of view of the object is 180 degrees as its a flat surface, so I have to magnify the object to say 2x , I will only get a 90degrees view angle of the same object...So theoretically speaking if I have a source which is 360 degrees in angle, then I can magnify it 2X and still get 360 degrees view. so if like my W,X,Y were written on a sphere then I can hope to get 2X magnification with 180 degrees view...

Comment: Practically speaking, if you have a (thin) candle, you can see it from almost every direction without the need for any optics. Adding optics to the candle doesn't make it any more visible because of energy and momentum conservation. You can't make $16\pi$ out of a full $4\pi$ full angle by using a (hypothetical) 2x magnification device.

Comment: I guess I have framed my question wrong. I am going to view the image from quiet a distance, so the rays can be assume parallel and collimated from image perspective. If that is the case then its is not 180 degrees view, but series of collimated or very low angle view from different angles.  I am uploading a diagram where I can see magnified version of the dot from 3 different directions with 3 different lens.

Comment: by the same logic if I arrange the lenses in hemi-spherical fashion...will it help..?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the trail of a "fisheye" lens.  If you spend enough money, you can get a lens with greater than $\pi$ Field of View in elevation. [(Yes, for real)](http://petapixel.com/2012/05/08/160000-nikkor-6mm-fisheye-in-action-on-a-nikon-d800/)    Here's one way to look at it:  if you can see the same image on the focal plane wherever you are, then the focal plane can "see" you wherever you are.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look.
It is very useful that you've provided the images. Basically what you say that every point on the surface of this "lens" will "emit" in every direction. Well I guess one just need to glue a paper on this lens so that it will nicely scatter the light, i.e. emit in every direction.

Will the image look like a point or a circle from the distance? More like a circle of course. But this is a consequence of the finite size of the aperture of your eye and restrictions which you put on the "lens".

This is probably not the kind of device you wanted. But the one which fits your images

Comment: Not really useful.